# Why does it come up with 'null' on my website when I try to print a user inputted word later on in the script?

Tags: javascript, html

Here's my html so far:

```html
<html>
<body>
<head>
<script>
Array.prototype.sample = function(){
  return this[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.length)];
}
var sentances = ['This new amazing product will be in every home by 2021','Buy this now- before we run out of stock!','Get this now, before everyone else will have one!'].sample()
var quotes = ['“This is amazing!"','"Buy it Now!"'].sample()
var titleback = ['"Nothing can beat','"How can you not love'].sample()
var title = document.getElementById("title")
function myfunction() {
document.getElementById("Sentances").innerHTML = sentances;
document.getElementById("Quotes").innerHTML = quotes;
document.getElementById("Titleback").innerHTML = titleback + title;
}
</script>
</head>

<h2>Auto Ad Generator</h2>

<p>Enter the title of your product:</p>
<form method="post" action=".">
<p><input name="name" id="title"></p>
<button type="button" id="button" onclick="myfunction()">Try it</button>
<p><input name="name2" type="reset"></p>
</form>
<p id="Sentances"></p>
<p id="Sentances2"></p>
<p id="Quotes"></p>
<p id="Titleback"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Though when I run this on the website (sites.google.com/view/generator-ad/home), it just prints the word 'null' next to the sentence randomly chosen from 'titleback'. Why does it do this, and not print the name of the product the user inputted at the start? I'm new to javascript and so sorry if the answer is obvious. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please be more specific: `null` is not the same as `[object HTMLInputElement]`

Comment: You want the `.value` property of the input element stored in `title`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`title` is a reference to an element. You can't output this to the page.

Instead you presumably want its `.value` property, to retrieve the value entered by the user.

```
document.getElementById("Titleback").innerHTML = titleback + title.value;
```

Answer (score 1):

`HtmlInputElement` means in this case that you are trying to print out the whole element, instead of the `value`.

I guess the following example can you help to solve your issue:

```js
Array.prototype.sample = function() { return this[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.length)] };

const submitButton = document.getElementById('submit');
const titleInput = document.getElementById('title');

submitButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const titleFromArray = ['"Nothing can beat','"How can you not love'].sample();      
  document.getElementById("Titleback").innerHTML = `${titleFromArray} ${titleInput.value}"`;
});
```

```html
<input id="title" name="name">
<p id="Titleback"></p>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

**+1 suggestion:**

Usually I like better naming convention. For example in this case when you use `getElementById` then I would suggest to use the variable name with the element type as well. Maybe this is just my personal preference. By doing this you will be sure that you are not mixing up values with DOM elements' references. For example in button case a better name can be just like `submitButton`. Other example:

```
const titleInput = document.getElementById('titleInput');
const title = titleInput.value;
```

I hope this helps!